# postman returning null with 200 status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

getting null value as response with 200 status code. i want to see the profile details as response but instead of that showing null value with no error status code in my postman i dont find any error on my code. why it shows like this ? i want to see profile details as response after sending

**[image]**

**Router.post**

```
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('status', 'Status is required').not().isEmpty(),
      check('skills', 'Skills cannot be empty').not().isEmpty(),
    ],
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    const {
      company,
      website,
      location,
      bio,
      status,
      githubusername,
      skills,
      youtube,
      twitter,
      instagram,
      linkedin,
    } = req.body;

    const profileFields = {};

    profileFields.user = req.user.id;

    if (company) profileFields.company = company;
    if (website) profileFields.website = website;
    if (location) profileFields.location = location;
    if (bio) profileFields.bio = bio;
    if (status) profileFields.status = status;
    if (githubusername) profileFields.githubusername = githubusername;
    if (skills) {
      profileFields.skills = skills.split(',').map(skill => skill.trim());
    }

    // creating object for socila links
    profileFields.social = {};

    if (youtube) profileFields.social.youtube = youtube;
    if (twitter) profileFields.social.twitter = twitter;
    if (instagram) profileFields.social.instagram = instagram;
    if (linkedin) profileFields.social.linkedin = linkedin;

    try {
      let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

      if (profile)
        //update
        profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFields },
          { new: true }
        );

      return res.json(profile);

      // create
      profile = new Profile(profileFields);
      await profile.save();
      res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('server error');
    }
  }
);
```

**here is profile schema looks like**

```
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  company: {
    type: String,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
  },
  githubusername: {
    type: String,
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      location: {
        type: String,
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: Date,
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: Date,
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String,
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String,
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String,
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile',ProfileSchema)
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect `profile`, what is it's value before you send it. Also the last part of your route handler is never to be reached because you return `res.json(profile)` directly after the `if (profile)` clause.

Comment: yeah that was the issue

Answer (score 1):

your code logic has problem.
`let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }); if (profile) //update profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate( { user: req.user.id }, { $set: profileFields }, { new: true } ); return res.json(profile);`
here, if you can't find the record in database, you still return and there is no value so that you got null response. i suggest you remoe the `return res.json(profile);` into `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

Back to the basics, the `if` statement.

```
  if (profile){
    //update
    profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
      { user: req.user.id },
      { $set: profileFields },
      { new: true }
    );

  return res.json(profile);
  }
```

You need to use brackets `{}`.

In your code, `return res.json(profile);` gets fired no matter if the response is `null` or not

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake i didn't saw that.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your syntax you need to add curly braces

```
if (profile){
    //update
    profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
      { user: req.user.id },
      { $set: profileFields },
      { new: true }
    )};
```